# debug ruby programs using gdb error: evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc"

Tags: ruby, debugging, gdb

Error message: `evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc".`

```
> gdb /Users/jani/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby  27300
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0".
Reading symbols from /Users/jani/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby...done.
Attaching to program: /Users/jani/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby, process 27300
[New Thread 0x1703 of process 27300]
0x0000000101fdfacf in ?? ()
(gdb) ruby_eval("puts 1")
evaluation of this expression requires the program to have a function "malloc".
```

Anyone has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Invoking "inferior function calls" from gdb (the ruby_eval("puts 1") bit) requires gdb to allocate some memory in the target process, so it can put a stack frame, parameters, etc. in there.  To do this, gdb normally causes the inferior process to run the C library malloc(3) function.  If gdb can't find malloc, your inferior function call won't be possible.

Comment: I know the cause partially but what's the solution, Why malloc could not be found?     It seems that malloc is not linked or ..!